# get-it verify command not recognized?

Tags: git

Another question has been posted identical to this.

However the answers did not seem to help.

I use Mac Os.

I downloaded git on Mac OS.

I set my username and email.

```
$ git config --global user.name "<Your Name>" 

$ git config --global user.email "<youremail@example.com>"
```

And now I try to verify by:

```
git-it verify
```

and it says:

> command not recognized.

When I type in git config user.name I see that my username has been what I set it as, and also my email when I use:

```
git config user.email
```

But why isn't the git-it verify command recognized?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that is a valid command?  Is something telling you to run that command?  If so, what?

Comment: Well...I am a student...and my reading is telling me that that command should go through...so...I'm just wondering why it doesn't go through.